# How can I solve "ERROR k.a.j.j.JMXMonSampler: The client has been closed" in JMeter after installing SSHMon Sample Collector in JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have a problem regarding running **jp@gc-Graph Generator** plugin  more than two times in my TestPlan in JMeter. I get following stacktrace in **Log Viewer panel** :

```
2020-08-25 17:23:29,114 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 192.168.1.5
2020-08-25 17:23:29,115 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,119 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting distributed test with remote engines: [192.168.1.5] @ Tue Aug 25 17:23:29 CEST 2020 (1598369009119)
2020-08-25 17:23:29,120 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method
2020-08-25 17:23:29,122 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,122 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,123 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,123 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,135 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,135 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,136 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-25 17:23:29,136 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-25 17:23:29,136 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,136 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,136 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-25 17:23:29,136 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-25 17:23:29,136 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,137 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,137 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-25 17:23:29,137 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-25 17:23:29,137 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,137 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,138 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-25 17:23:29,138 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-25 17:23:29,138 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,138 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,138 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-25 17:23:29,138 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-25 17:23:29,138 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,139 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,139 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-25 17:23:29,139 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-25 17:23:29,139 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,139 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,139 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-25 17:23:29,139 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-25 17:23:29,139 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,139 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,140 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-25 17:23:29,140 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-25 17:23:29,140 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,140 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,140 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-25 17:23:29,140 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-25 17:23:29,140 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,140 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,141 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2020-08-25 17:23:29,141 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
2020-08-25 17:23:29,183 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: sent test to 192.168.1.5 basedir='JMX-files/TestPlanS'
2020-08-25 17:23:29,183 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Sending properties {}
2020-08-25 17:23:29,194 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: sent run command to 192.168.1.5
2020-08-25 17:23:29,194 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started:[192.168.1.5]
2020-08-25 17:23:29,234 ERROR k.a.j.j.JMXMonSampler: The client has been closed.

2020-08-25 17:23:29,292 ERROR k.a.j.j.JMXMonSampler: The client has been closed.
2020-08-25 17:23:29,361 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, 192.168.1.5)
2020-08-25 17:23:30,245 ERROR k.a.j.j.JMXMonSampler: The client has been closed.
// ... a LOT of SAME ERROR messages
2020-08-25 17:23:50,124 ERROR k.a.j.j.JMXMonSampler: The client has been closed.
2020-08-25 17:23:51,413 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, 192.168.1.5)
```

This is screenshot of my TestPlan:
[image]

As you can see I've **disabled** *SSHMon Sample Collector* Listener

Also, due to problem running Graph Generator plugin (i.e. generating graphs for real) I've mannually added JMeter-Extras.jar file in `lib/ext` directory of my apache-jmeter installation by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42923483/6805866) answer. That didn't help, so later I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42391444/6805866) from @Dmitri T and installed  ***Synthesis Report*** and Graph Generator worked as it should. Later I've installed SSHMon Sample Collector and since then I'm having this issue which is dipslayed in stacktrace and **no CSV results, nor graphs are being genreated IFF Test Plan is ran more than 2 times**.

Any help/advice is more than greatly appreciated.

**P.S.** I'm using **JMeter 5.2.1, Fedora 31 64-bit OS** and **Java 8 (build 1.8.0_161-b12)**.